# How we determine the ground truth box of the object in each frame in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

When we track one object in a video sequence using a tracking object method, the estimated bounding box is given by the method for every frame of the video. But how we determine the ground truth box of the object in each frame, because we need both boxes to evaluate performances of the tracking method.

Answer (score 0):

You ask a human to draw a box around the object on each frame of your video.